# Overriding META-INF\services\org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am working with hibernate envers (4.3.5 version). Using Conditional auditing (15.8. hibernate envers doc) I inherited EnversIntegrator creating my own customerEnversIntegrator. for making envers to use this one, I added to META-INF\services\org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator the customerEnversIntegrator path. it worked fine! When i left it as default, but changed the application META-INF\services\org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator to point the customerEnversIntegrator was not used fully. so it actually didn't work But i don't want this declaration to be in the jar level. i need to override it from the application. cause as a project - i can't control the jar, it could be updated and etc.

Any ideas how to override this file without changing anything in the Jar?

Comment: I updated my answer with a less invasive option that should allow you to place your `Integrator` in your application code and avoid having to change anything in the `hibernate-envers` library.

Comment: I have already added hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister=false but problem is same.

Comment: What does 'was not used fully' then mean?  It sounds like the `Integrator` was fired so perhaps its your implementation that is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Envers conditional auditing setup is invasive, this is precisely why Envers 6 wants to take a different approach that is less intrusive.

What you can do is to turn off the standard Envers `Integrator` implementation by specifying the Hibernate configuration property which will cause the standard integrator for envers to not start and not register the standard event listeners, etc.

```
hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister=false
```

Then you register your own custom `Integrator` that mimics the standard implementation but instead does not check for the existance of the above configuration property for obvious reasons and that registers your custom listeners rather than the standard ones.

That should avoid having to manually change the `hibernate-envers` artifact or do any build time library manipulation.

I most likely will remove this configuration option in the future as the annotated conditional auditing approach will become the preferred choice here and to avoid having to force users who want this to duplicate internal code in order to use such functionality.

Comment: How can I create customized history for now.

Comment: This is the only way to conditionally control audit history from an Envers perspective.  The other way is to do this at the application layer, database triggers, or write your own entity state comparison mechanism using Hibernate listeners.

Comment: I have used hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister=false , but  my custom event listener is not getting fired.I think a change in hibernate-envers artifact is required to fire my own Integrator.